# Dynamically created labels won't display on the screen pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am making a basic GUI application using PyQt5, and need to create `labels` dynamically after user input. Now, the problem is they won't show on the screen, although the objects themselves are created. This function is getting called on button press after user finishes input:

```
def set_result_labels(self):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        for i in range(len(self.text_parties_names)):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            setattr(self, f"label_{i+5}", label)
            label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, (100+4*i), 50, 50))
            label.setFont(font)
            label.setText(self.text_parties_names[i])
            label.setObjectName(f"label_{i+5}")
```

But, if I "explicitly" create them, like this:

```
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 400, 171, 40))
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setText(self.text_parties_names[0])
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_25")
```

It works with no issues. I do not understand why.

Comment: I can only guess right now, but maybe overwriting the `label` variable every loop isn't a good idea. Try saving all labels in a list

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: add `label.show()`

Comment: @eyllanesc actually this solves the issue, I can't believe it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

as an option, you can insert the `label` in the `layout`, for example like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        button.clicked.connect(self.set_result_labels)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(200)
        scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(200)
        scrollArea.setWidget(widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(scrollArea) 
        layout.addStretch(1)  
        layout.addWidget(button)  

        self.text_parties_names = '12345'

    def set_result_labels(self):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        for i in range(len(self.text_parties_names)):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            setattr(self, f"label_{i+5}", label)
#            label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, (100+4*i), 50, 50))
            label.setFont(font)
            label.setText(self.text_parties_names[i])
            label.setObjectName(f"label_{i+5}") 

            self.scroll_box.addWidget(label)                                # <<<---


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc suggestion worked, but I also like your approach. I am new to PyQt5 and you gave a great idea.

Comment: @kaktus_car the choice is always yours :)